# Family Sharing Age Appropriate

Tags: itunes, family-sharing

I currently have a family set up and family turned on. However it seems to be very all or nothing.

If I share my iTunes purchases with my family is there a way to age restrict the content they see so they only see films/tv series appropriate to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Age restrictions are controlled with "Screen Time"

This article has general instructions on setting up Screen Time:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982

And this article has instructions on the parental controls you're looking for:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304

> Prevent explicit content and content ratings
>
> You can also prevent the playback of music with explicit content and movies or TV shows with specific ratings. Apps also have ratings that can be configured using content restrictions.
>
> To restrict explicit content and content ratings:
> Go to Settings and tap Screen Time.
> Tap Content & Privacy Restrictions, then tap Content Restrictions.
> Choose the settings that you want for each feature or setting under Allowed Store Content.